# Join two dataframes with the closest date and exact string

Tags: r, left-join, data.table

So the two data frame looks like this:

df1

```
Date      |    Route   |   Value1

2014-01-01 |    ABE:XXY |   122.32
```

---

df2

```
Date | Route | Value2

2014-01-07 | ABE:XXY | 10,231
```

---

Here, two dataframe's key should be Route and Date.
I want data frame to join on exact routes and nearest date.

---

I have tried data.table rolling join but it gives nearest match for both the keys.

Comment: `{data.table}`'s rolling join should work. You have to make sure that the Date is the last key in both tables (i.e, you key them using `setkey(df1,Route,Date)`), and Date is in proper format. After that you should be able to do rolling join to nearest date with `df2[df1,roll='nearest']`

Comment: Depends also a bit on which date you want to keep. The max, min, the one from df1 or df2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..it helps..but there is one more roadblock -- what if we have two rows in df2 which can be joined to the one (date,route) key in df1 and in that case i want to sum both the value2 and after then join it with the df1..it sounds complicated..is this possible ? again thanks for help

Comment: @Pratik409 You can self answer your question to not leave it *open* or just delete it.